# How do I convert a base64 encoded string to a Stream that I can use with FileStorage from werkzeug.datastructures?

Tags: python

I need this because I am using AJAX to transfer a file, hence I get an image file in a base64 encoded string. I would like to convert this nicely to the FileStorage object so I can use flask-uploads library nicely. Any idea how I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def open_file(file_name):
    """
    opens file in samples, and return base64 encoded streams.
        feel free to use this code if it is helpful.
    """
    from backend import backend
    sample_dir = backend.config["samples_dir"]
    file = open(os.path.join(sample_dir, file_name), 'r')
    stream = file.read()
    encoded_stream = base64.b64encode(stream)
    return encoded_stream
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is an answer to the question. How does this tie to flask-uploads?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the pickle module, specifically the [pickle.load](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) function. This module assists with converting objects to and from byte streams.

You may also need to convert your string using [binascii](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#binascii.a2b_base64).